# 3 dimensional array split in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have problem with split. I have a long string, and i want fill it in 3 dimensional array.

```
var str = "normal/zapnout-0-1/vypnout-1-1%nocni/zapnout-2-1/vypnout-3-1*list/film-4-1/manual-5-1/auto-6-1*obyvak/světlo-7-1/krb-8-1/žaluzie-9-1/televize-10-1%světlo-11-1/okno-12-1%světlo-13-1/okno-14-1%pokoj/světlo-15-1";
 var res = str.split("*");
 var res2 = new Array();
 var res3 = new Array();

 for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
     res2[i] = res[i].split("%");
     for (var t = 0; t < res2[i].length; t++) {
         res3[i]= new Array();
         res3[i][t]=res2[i][t].split("/");
     }
 }
 document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = res3;
```

But problem is, result from res3 is:

> *,nocni,zapnout-2-1,vypnout-3-1,list,film-4-1,manual-5-1,auto-6-1,,,,pokoj,světlo-15-1*

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: please use `var res2 = [];` much more elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var str = "normal/zapnout-0-1/vypnout-1-1%nocni/zapnout-2-1/vypnout-3-1*list/film-4-1/manual-5-1/auto-6-1*obyvak/světlo-7-1/krb-8-1/žaluzie-9-1/televize-10-1%světlo-11-1/okno-12-1%světlo-13-1/okno-14-1%pokoj/světlo-15-1";
 var res = str.split("*");
 for(var i=0; i< res.length;i++){
     res[i] = res[i].split("%");
     for(var j=0;j< res[i].length;j++){
         res[i][j] = res[i][j].split("/");
     }
 }
 console.log(res);
```

Also just for you to know, your code has the issue of reinitializing res3[i] instead of making it res3[i][t]. This should be your code :

```
 var str = "normal/zapnout-0-1/vypnout-1-1%nocni/zapnout-2-1/vypnout-3-1*list/film-4-1/manual-5-1/auto-6-1*obyvak/světlo-7-1/krb-8-1/žaluzie-9-1/televize-10-1%světlo-11-1/okno-12-1%světlo-13-1/okno-14-1%pokoj/světlo-15-1";
var res = str.split("*");
var res2 = new Array();
var res3 = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    res2[i] = res[i].split("%");
    res3[i] = new Array();
    for (var t = 0; t < res2[i].length; t++) {
        res3[i][t]= new Array();
        res3[i][t]=res2[i][t].split("/");
    }
}
```

But please stop using the variables in this way because for a big application this will be a memory killer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. By default JavaScript strips the brackets and quotes when printing arrays.

```
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res3);
```

Here is a working implementation of the logic:

```
var res3 = str.split('*').map(function(segment) {
    return segment.split('%').map(function(segment) {
        return segment.split('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: That say [[null,["nocni","zapnout-2-1","vypnout-3-1"]],[["list","film-4-1","manual-5-1","auto-6-1"]],[null,null,null,["pokoj","světlo-15-1"]]]

Comment: Then I don't know what you are expecting.

Comment: I want
`[[["normal/zapnout-0-1/vypnout-1-1"],["nocni","zapnout-2-1","vypnout-3-1"]],[["list","film-4-1","manual-5-1","auto-6-1"]],[["obyvak","světlo-7-1","krb-8-1","žaluzie-9-1","televize-10-1"],["světlo-11-1","okno-12-1"],["světlo-13-1","světlo-141"],["pokoj","světlo-15-1"]]]` Without null.

Comment: @sabof I up voted your answer, but try to give an answer without the use of ES5 because these kind of "developers" will start asking about the errors that they receive because of the use of map function in IE 8. ;)

Comment: @helly0d thanks. I just thought that this makes much more sense with `.map`.

Comment: @sabof It does, but not for the ones still using JavaScript tag for something that is pure algorithm, and also for those who think JavaScript == JQuery. ;)